# Will every such injective function be a bijection?

Tags: functions

Say I have two sets $A$ and $B$ (possibly infinite). I have an injective function $f:A\to B$ and another injective function $B\to A$. Can I conclude then that every injective function $c:A\to B$ will be a bijection?

Thanks

Comment: No, consider $A=B=\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Why would you think that?

Comment: A bijection occurs when it's both a surjection (onto) and an injection (one-to-one)

Comment: Yes, but if you have injections from both $A$ and $B$, then you get $n(A)=n(B)$ in finite cases...

Comment: By the Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder theorem, **there is** a bijection from $A$ to $B$. But if the sets are not finite, there will be many injections that are not bijections.

Answer (score 0):

No. But you can concluse that there exists *some* bijective function $c \,:\, A \to B$,.

This is because $f \,:\, A \to B$ being injective tells you that the *cardinality* or $B$ is as least as large as the cardinality of $A$ - otherwise $B$ won't include enough elements to assign a *different* element of $B$ to each element of $A$. And conversely, $g \,:\, B \to A$ tells you that the cardinality of $A$ is at least as large as that of $B$.

So you have $|A| \leq |B|$ and $|B| \leq |A|$, and since the cardinals are totally ordered (which is proved by the cantor-bernstein-schroeder theorem), it follows that $|A| = |B|$, which means that there exists some bijection between $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Funny. Your claim *is* the Cantor-Bernstein-Schröder theorem.

Comment: @vonbrand Which is why I wrote "... (which is proved by the Cantor-Bernstein-Schröder theorem)..."

Answer (score 0):

No. Consider $A = B = \mathbb{Z}$. The inyections you claim clearly exist. But the inyection $n \mapsto 2 n$ is not a biyection.